# How to get datatable column values in comma separated based on another column which have repeated/duplicated values?

Tags: c#-4.0, datatable

I need to get data-table column values in comma separated based on another column which have repeated/duplicated values. That is based on the first column value I need to get the comma separated values of the second column for each unique value in first column. Below is my current table.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Col1</th>
<th>Col2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>AAA</td>
<tr>  
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>BBB</td>
<tr>   
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>CCC</td>
<tr>   
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>DDD</td>
<tr>    
<tr>
<td>E</td>
<td>EEE</td>
<tr>    
<tr>
<td>F</td>
<td>FFF</td>
<tr>    
</table>
```

Expected Output:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2<th>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD</td>
    <tr>  
<tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>EEE</td>
    <tr>    
    <tr>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>FFF</td>
    <tr>    
</table>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is the data format is XML as your example or is data in some kind of database. You may need to provide more context information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. Sorry for that, I tried to display it in Table format. So i used table tag. No xml, normal C# DATA-TABLE